# Custom 404 error handler in htaccess not working for non-existent ".php" files

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I'm using a custom error handing system.

Example `.htaccess` file command:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-deal.php?code=404
```

The `error-deal.php` file is present and processes $_GET variables as it should if I enter the URL directly.

Pages with file extensions don't trigger the `.htaccess` redirect to the error page:

```
https://example.com/does-not-exist.php
```

And yet URLs without the extension do...

```
https://example.com/does-not-exist
```

What am I missing here?

Other rewrite rules are:

```
#force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

#redirect all www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.donbur.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) https://donbur.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#URL re-writes for dynamic pages
    
#to handle all news requests
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /gb-en/news/article.php?title=$1 [L]

#to handle all feature requests
RewriteRule ^features/([^/]*)$ /gb-en/features/feature.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in either your Apache config or in the htaccess? If so, please show them as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks - I've added the only conditions and rules I can find.

Comment: "Pages with file extensions" - Specifically, it would seem to be only `.php` extensions. This maybe to do with the way PHP is installed on your system. For instance, if all `*.php` requests are proxied to an alternative server/process then this is going to bypass your `.htaccess` file on the application server.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite. Regrettably, we have no control over this shared server and do not have access to the config files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pages with file extensions don't trigger the htaccess redirect to the error page:

As mentioned in comments, this would seem to only affect URLs that have a `.php` extension. This might be due to the way PHP is implemented on your server. For instance, if all `*.php` requests are proxied to an alternative backend process then this is going to bypass your `.htaccess` file on the application server.

Unfortunately, since this would appear to be a *shared server*, you may not have any control over this.

However, there are a couple of things you could try. Although this is hampered by the fact you appear to be using URLs that end in `.php` throughout your site.

Try resetting the default error document *before* setting your custom error document. The `ErrorDocument` should override a previous setting, however, sometimes when this is defined in the server config, it doesn't. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 404 /error-deal.php?code=404
```

If it wasn't for the fact you are using `.php` URLs on your site (although, confusingly, you seem to have a mixture of `.php` and extensionless URLs throughout your site?) then you could potentially force all `.php` requests to a 404 using mod_rewrite (although this still may not override the default error response).

You could try the following *after* your canonical redirects (HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www):

```
# Force a 404 for ".php" requests that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

If you didn't have any `.php` URLs then you could remove the preceding `RewriteCond` directive.

---

*Aside:* You should make sure the `/error-deal.php` document itself isn't directly accessible. This currently returns a 200 OK status for non-errors and there doesn't seem to be anything (robots meta tag, response header, `robots.txt`) that prevents search engines from crawling/indexing this page(s).

Comment: The ErrorDocument 404 default wasn't effective; however, forcing a 404 for non existent php requests did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm using a mixture of extensions as some of the site is static (.php) and some is dynamic on a custom CMS.  I'm using RewriteRule to change any ugly .php?title=messy to just /messy  .  Is a php extension preferred (i.e. /messy.php)?