# htacces wrong configuration when gets .php not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am fighting with .htaccess file and I need some help for resolve my problem.

I try to configure the file .htaccess for:

- delete extensions
- shows 404 error

but something its wrong, I try to explained:

- page.php (that exists) -> page #OK
- pagenotfound (that not exits) -> redirect 404 # OK
- pagenotfound.php (the same like other only with extension) -> shows File not found # ERROR

This is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -Indexes

php_value default_charset None
AddDefaultCharset utf-8


ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]


#rewrite http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# remove extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Though your configuration file certainly could use some cleanup it should work for what you describe. Are you sure you are not looking at a cached result from earlier attempts with that request to `pagenotfound.php`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom 404 error handler in htaccess not working for non-existent ".php" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69361909/custom-404-error-handler-in-htaccess-not-working-for-non-existent-php-files)

Comment: _Aside:_ Why are you wanting to "redirect" to the 404 page?