# htaccess - redirect to error pages issue (with slash or without slash)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

There is an issue with redirection to error pages:
`example.com/test` - will redirect to 404 error page

but
`example.com/test/` - will go to the white "File not found." page

to mention:

- it was working properly until some time ago (maybe update of PHP version ??)
- same behavior with www/http/https version of the links
- standard structure of the links is `www.example.com/test/`

#### .htaccess file code

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteRule sample/(.*)/(.*)/$ /sample.php?$1=$2

ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /410.php
```

Comment: So does `test.php` exist in the first place?

Comment: no, there is no file test.php, no folder also

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `404.php` to make sure it is still valid? Maybe switch it to a static file for debugging.

Comment: yes, the content of the 404.php file is correct, and I would prefer to stick to PHP version.

Comment: i made the test with static file - result is the same( static file will show in case of (example.com/test), but in case of (example.com/test/) - will go to the white "File not found." page

Comment: I believe `example.com/test/` gets rewritten to `test.php` and for some dumb reason or misconfiguration, the php interpreter is fired but with the wrong filename. Try opening the url `example.com/test.php` and see if shows same error

Comment: Please also specify where the rewrite rules are located. Inside a `.htaccess` that is present inside root or inside `VirtualHost` section.

Comment: example.com/test.php goes to white "File not found." page

Comment: Do you have two error pages?

Comment: "will go to the white "File not found." page" - Is that literally all it says "File not found."? Or is it a more complete default server response? Please include the complete response in the question. Also, please include the HTTP response headers you are seeing with this "File not found" response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference with your URLs that end in a trailing slash is that they are unconditionally rewritten to the corresponding `.php` file. The URLs that do not end in a trailing slash are not rewritten - nothing happens.

You are seeing the same basic "File not found" response when you directly request a non-existent `.php` file, regardless of whether the request is rewritten (by your rules) or not.

The "problem" might be due to the way PHP is implemented on your server. For instance, if all `*.php` requests are proxied to an alternative backend process then this is going to bypass your `.htaccess` file on the application server and the "basic" 404 response you are seeing is possibly coming from the proxy, not your application server.

You may be able to resolve this by first checking that the `.php` exists before rewriting to it (so it doesn't trigger a 404). And if none of your *URLs* contain a `.php` extension, you could also force any direct request for `.php` files to 404 (on your server, before the request is proxied - if that is what's happening).

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
> RewriteRule sample/(.*)/(.*)/$ /sample.php?$1=$2
> ```

The first two rules can also be combined into one. You are missing `L` flags on all your rules. You need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled, otherwise the last rule will not work.

Also, the regex in the last rule needs to be *anchored* and made more specific since it is matching too much, eg. `/sample/foo/bar/baz/qux` will be rewritten to `/sample.php?foo/bar/baz=qux`, which I assume is not the intention.

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Force any direct request for ".php" files to 404
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]

# Rewrite to ".php" file - 1 or 2 path segments
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+(/[^/]+)?)/$ $1.php [L]

# Rewrite "/sample/one/two/"
RewriteRule ^sample/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ sample.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

---

Reference:

Another recent question that has a very similar issue and was resolved in the same way:
[Custom 404 error handler in htaccess not working for non-existent ".php" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69361909/custom-404-error-handler-in-htaccess-not-working-for-non-existent-php-files)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with ending slash of `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php`

If you write `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php` the tailing slash would be optional.

**edit**

You should also add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

before `RewriteRule` statements, because of server loop - when the file exists the statements will break loop by skipping rewriting.

Comment: with this change/update i get "Internal Server Error"

Comment: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: There should be more information in your site's error_log about what caused the 500 error.  Can you look there and report what it says?

Comment: "The problem is with ending slash" - That itself is not a problem. The trailing slash would appear to be present on the OPs URLs. By simply making the trailing slash optional it will result in a rewrite-loop (Internal Server Error) since `test.php` will itself be rewritten to `test.php.php` etc. (which would then necessitate the need for additional filesystem checks, as mentioned in the edit). But making the trailing slash _optional_ is unnecessary and potentially creates a duplicate content issue (redirect to append the slash if you want to).