# Custom ErrorDocument 404 page not working for the PHP extension, works for everything else

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Update 08/02/2022**

I've setup a custom ErrorDocument 404 page. Here is my htaccess rule for it.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php

RewriteEngine On
```

After much testing I've realized it works flawlessly for everything except php pages. If its a bad directory being hit, or any other file extension it works.

**Examples of links where the custom 404 error page  successfully displays**

- https://www.example.com/bad-file.html
- https://www.example.com/bad-folder/bad-file.html
- https://www.example.com/bad-folder/bad-file.php
- https://www.example.com/existing-folder/bad-file.html
- https://www.example.com/existing-folder/bad-image.jpg

**Examples of links where the custom 404 error page fails to display**

- https://www.example.com/bad-file.php
- https://www.example.com/existing-folder/bad-file.php

I thought maybe it had to do with some of my rewrite rules in my htaccess, but completely stripped them all for testing purposes and still have the same issue.

Comment: You need to be setting to your absolute path .. IE: `ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/example.com/public_html/not-found.php`.  Essentially your 404 is 404-ing LOL

Comment: I did as suggested using the correct file path for my directory and it did not work. The pages that were working no longer work with that method as well. Plesk has the root for the site setup as /var/www/example.com/ so I'm guessing thats why, /var/www does not exist in htacces's eyes

Comment: @Zak no, a file system path would be completely wrong. Check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument, option/method #3 is, _"internally redirect to **a local URL-path** to handle the problem/error"_

Answer (score 1):

I finally found someone else with my issue and the solution provided solved it for me. Here is the issue post

[Custom 404 error handler in htaccess not working for non-existent ".php" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69361909/custom-404-error-handler-in-htaccess-not-working-for-non-existent-php-files)

Here was the solution for the php extension to work:

```
# Force a 404 for ".php" requests that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```